# check if subset of rows is NA then move adjacent rows to replace them

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe that's a result of combining multiple sheets from excel. The columns did not align properly. I need to check if a subset of rows is all NA. If they are NA, then I need to check if the adjacent equally sized subset has content, and if it does, I need to copy over that row to replace the NAs.

This is what the data looks like from my dput:

```
structure(list(id = 1:20, A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c", "d", 
"q", "p", "m", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "k", "o", "i", "a", "b"), 
    B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "h", "a", "f", "b", "e", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "m", "c", "s", "g", "p"), C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "a", "f", "j", "s", "g", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "l", "m", 
    "o", "k", "t"), D = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "n", "r", "l", 
    "h", "g", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "j", "p", "f", "d", "q"), E = c("j", 
    "p", "n", "i", "g", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "k", "e", "s", "m", 
    "l", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), F = c("o", "d", "r", "q", "a", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "h", "s", "f", "j", "k", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), G = c("f", "c", "a", "l", "m", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "n", "t", "s", "e", "r", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), H = c("r", 
    "c", "h", "i", "j", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f", "e", "b", "l", 
    "n", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have equal number of non-missing values in each row as shown in the shared example you can drop `NA` values in each row.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, na.omit)))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1   1  j  o  f  r
#2   2  p  d  c  c
#3   3  n  r  a  h
#4   4  i  q  l  i
#5   5  g  a  m  j
#6   6  c  h  a  n
#7   7  d  a  f  r
#8   8  q  f  j  l
#9   9  p  b  s  h
#10 10  m  e  g  g
#11 11  k  h  n  f
#12 12  e  s  t  e
#13 13  s  f  s  b
#14 14  m  j  e  l
#15 15  l  k  r  n
#16 16  k  m  l  j
#17 17  o  c  m  p
#18 18  i  s  o  f
#19 19  a  g  k  d
#20 20  b  p  t  q
```

---

To check for 1st half values and if all of them are `NA` we select second half we can do :

```
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
  x1 <- (length(x)/2)
  if(all(is.na(x[1:x1]))) x[(x1+1):length(x)]
  else x[1:x1]
})))
```

Comment: There won't always be an equal amount of non-missing values. But if the first 4 values in the row are missing then I know that I need to copy over the adjacent 4 values.

Comment: Could you share such an example then? Also what would be output in such case? Let's say 1st row has 4 non-missing value and second row for has 5 non-missing values. Will you have 1 `NA` value in 1st row?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah If the first 4 values in the row are NA, and out of the adjacent 4 values in the same row have 3 values then 1 value would be NA. I want to move the last 4 columns to be the first 4 columns only if the first 4 values are NA. Unfortunately I can't share the data.

Comment: The update deletes an entire column. I'm going to see what else is particular about the dataset and then I'll comment.